# Как проверить что в поле textarea введен ноль?

Tags: php, javascript

Я пробовал разными способами, но или поле воспринимается как пустое (false) или скрипт вообще не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверять будем это чудо:

```
 <input id="lol" name="lol"/>
```

**js**:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // some code .....
    var lol = document.getElementById("lol");
    if(lol.value === '0') {/*валидная проверка на 0 в js*/}
}
```

**php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['lol']) && $_POST['lol'] == '0') {/* а это проверка в PHP... */}
// !empty в данном случае не наш путь и вот почему:
```

---

```
$zero = '0';
var_dump(!empty($zero)); //-> bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Преобразовывайте в строку.